[Gradle 8.1.2/Java 17/Micronaut 4.1.6]-Cannot set the value of task ':collectReachabilityMetadata' when I try to update micronaut from 3.8.4 to 4.1.6
I have a webbapp with java 17 and gradle 8.2.1, when I try to update micronaut version from 3.8.4 to 4.1.6 I recived the following error:
Could not create task ':collectReachabilityMetadata'.
Cannot set the value of task ':collectReachabilityMetadata' property 'metadataService' of type org.graalvm.buildtools.gradle.internal.GraalVMReachabilityMetadataService using a provider of type org.graalvm.buildtools.gradle.internal.GraalVMReachabilityMetadataService.
This is my gradle configuration:
plugins {
    id 'project-report'
    id("com.github.johnrengelman.shadow") version "8.1.1"
    id("io.micronaut.application") version "4.2.0"
    id("org.owasp.dependencycheck") version "7.1.1"
    id("org.sonarqube") version "5.0.0.4638"
    id("org.liquibase.gradle") version "2.2.2"
    id('jacoco')
}

version = "1.1.1"

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven {
        url "https://jaspersoft.jfrog.io/jaspersoft/third-party-ce-artifacts"
    }
}

micronaut {
    version '4.1.6'
    runtime("netty")
    testRuntime("junit5")
    processing {
        incremental(true)
        annotations("my.class.main.*")
        annotations("my.class.test.*")
    }
}

jacocoTestReport {
    reports {
        xml.required = true
        csv.required = false
        html.outputLocation = layout.buildDirectory.dir('reports/tests/coverageReport')
    }
}

dependencyCheck {
    formats = ["JSON", "HTML"]
    suppressionFiles = ["${projectDir}/config/dependencyCheck/suppressions.xml"]
}

sonarqube {
    properties {
        property 'sonar.host.url', "${sonar_host_url}"
        property 'sonar.login', "${sonar_login}"
        property "sonar.dependencyCheck.jsonReportPath", "$buildDir/reports/dependency-check-report.json"
        property "sonar.dependencyCheck.htmlReportPath", "$buildDir/reports/dependency-check-report.html"
    }
}

test {
    finalizedBy jacocoTestReport // report is always generated after tests run
}

dependencies {
    //DEPENDENCIA DE MFTCore
    implementation("MFTCore:lib:3.1.1")

    //DEPENDENCIAS MINIMAS DE MICRONAUT
    annotationProcessor("io.micronaut:micronaut-http-validation")
    implementation("io.micronaut.validation:micronaut-validation")
    implementation("io.micronaut.liquibase:micronaut-liquibase")
    implementation 'com.google.zxing:javase:3.5.0'
    implementation 'com.google.zxing:core:3.5.0'
    implementation("com.sun.mail:jakarta.mail:2.0.0")
    annotationProcessor("io.micronaut:micronaut-management:3.2.0")


    implementation("io.micronaut:micronaut-http-client")

    implementation("io.micronaut.data:micronaut-data-hibernate-jpa")
    implementation("io.micronaut.security:micronaut-security-jwt")

    //SWAGGER
    annotationProcessor("io.micronaut.openapi:micronaut-openapi")
    implementation("io.swagger.core.v3:swagger-annotations")
    implementation("io.micronaut.openapi:micronaut-openapi:4.5.2")
    implementation 'org.bouncycastle:bcprov-jdk18on:1.72'
    implementation 'org.bouncycastle:bcpkix-jdk18on:1.72'
    implementation 'javax.xml.bind:jaxb-api'
    implementation "org.glassfish.jaxb:jaxb-runtime:${jaxWsVersion}"
    //Liquibase
    liquibaseRuntime("org.liquibase:liquibase-core:3.8.1")
    liquibaseRuntime("org.liquibase:liquibase-groovy-dsl:2.1.1")
    liquibaseRuntime("org.postgresql:postgresql")
    liquibaseRuntime("org.liquibase.ext:liquibase-hibernate5:4.3.5")
    liquibaseRuntime("org.yaml:snakeyaml:1.8")
    liquibaseRuntime('org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-all:3.0.12')
    implementation('com.github.spullara.mustache.java:compiler:0.9.10')
    implementation('net.sf.jasperreports:jasperreports:6.20.0')
    implementation('net.sf.jasperreports:jasperreports-functions:6.20.0')
    implementation('net.sf.jasperreports:jasperreports-fonts:6.20.0')
    liquibaseRuntime files(sourceSets.getByName("main").compileClasspath)
    liquibaseRuntime files(sourceSets.getByName("main").runtimeClasspath)
    liquibaseRuntime files(sourceSets.getByName("main").output)

    //Test
    testImplementation('org.mockito:mockito-core:4.10.0')
    testImplementation('org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter:5.8.1')
    testImplementation('org.testcontainers:testcontainers:1.17.6')
    testImplementation('org.testcontainers:junit-jupiter:1.17.6')
    testRuntimeOnly("org.testcontainers:postgresql")
    runtimeOnly("io.micronaut.sql:micronaut-jdbc-hikari")
    implementation("io.micronaut.sql:micronaut-jdbc-hikari")
    testImplementation 'com.github.rweisleder:jfairy-junit-extension:0.2.0'

    //Cache
    implementation('io.micronaut.cache:micronaut-cache-caffeine')
    implementation('io.micronaut.cache:micronaut-cache-management')

    //ELK
    implementation("org.codehaus.janino:janino:3.1.9")
    runtimeOnly("net.logstash.logback:logstash-logback-encoder:7.2")
    runtimeOnly('ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:1.2.11')
    runtimeOnly('ch.qos.logback:logback-access:1.2.11')
    runtimeOnly 'org.fusesource.jansi:jansi:2.4.0'

    // dependencies to call AFIP WS
    implementation(project(':afip-connector'))
    implementation(project(':ap-connector'))
    implementation(project(':ai-connector'))
    implementation(project(':taco-connector'))
    compileOnly "jakarta.xml.ws:jakarta.xml.ws-api:3.0.1"
    implementation 'com.sun.xml.ws:rt:4.0.1'
    runtimeOnly("org.yaml:snakeyaml")
    
}
apply plugin: "org.liquibase.gradle"

application {
    mainClass.set("my.class.main.Application")
}

java {
    sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.toVersion("17")
    targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.toVersion("17")
}

ultima version de MFTCore
configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy.cacheDynamicVersionsFor(1, "minutes")
}

shadowJar {
    zip64 true
}

tasks.withType(Test).configureEach {
    if (JavaVersion.current().majorVersion.toInteger() >= 17) {
        // This is required for JFairy mock person data generation
        it.jvmArgs += ['--add-opens', 'java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED']
    }
}

